# How to annotate parent classmethod so that child methods return an instance of themselves?

Tags: python, inheritance, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I have a parent class `BaseBlob` that has several child classes `LimitedProofId`, `ProofId`, `TxId`. The parent class implement a `deserialize` class method that should return an instance of itself.

I also have a `Delegation` class that takes a `LimitedProofId`. I specifically want *mypy* to error if I pass by mistake another child instance of `BaseBlob` such as a `ProofId` or a `TxId`.

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from io import BytesIO


class BaseBlob:
    def __init__(self, data: bytes):
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, stream: BytesIO) -> BaseBlob:
        return cls(stream.read(32))


class LimitedProofId(BaseBlob):
    pass


class TxId(BaseBlob):
    pass


class Delegation:
    def __init__(self, ltd_id: LimitedProofId):
        self.ltd_id = ltd_id

    def deserialize(self, stream: BytesIO) -> Delegation:
        ltd_id = LimitedProofId.deserialize(stream)
        return Delegation(ltd_id)
```

*mypy* shows an error for this code, because if thinks `LimitedProofId.deserialize` returns a `BaseBlob`.

```
error: Argument 1 to "Delegation" has incompatible type "BaseBlob"; expected "LimitedProofId"  [arg-type]
```

I have seen answer to similar questions that use a `T = TypeVar('T', bound='BaseBlob')` to achieve a type annotation that allows child classes, but if I do that I need to specify `T` both for the return type of `BaseBlob.deserialize` and the first parameter of `Delegation.__init__`, which defeat my purpose of type safety for the latter.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do, without having to reimplement `deserialize` on all child classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to express that `deserialize` returns an instance of the class that it is bound to.

### Python `>=3.9, <3.11`

```py
...
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="BaseBlob")

class BaseBlob:
    ...

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls: type[T], stream: BytesIO) -> T:
        return cls(stream.read(32))
```

These changes make the code you posted above perfectly type safe and `mypy --strict` agrees.

Calling from a child class like `LimitedProofId.deserialize` binds the method, so that `cls` will be `LimitedProofId`, which from a typing perspective in turn binds `T` in `type[T]` accordingly.

---

### Python `<3.9`

Like the above, but import [`Type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Type) from `typing` and replace the `type[T]` annotation with `Type[T]`.

---

### Python `>=3.11`

[What @chepner said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74734509/19770795). Should work soon with `mypy`.

---

### Clarification

I don't understand, what you mean: (highlighted)

> I have seen answer to similar questions that use a `T = TypeVar('T', bound='BaseBlob')` to achieve a type annotation that allows child classes, but if I do that I need to specify `T` both for the return type of `BaseBlob.deserialize` **and the first parameter of `Delegation.__init__`**, which defeat my purpose of type safety for the latter.

What does `__init__` have to do with this?

If I failed to understand your intention, please elaborate and I will do my best to adjust the answer.

---

### Addendum

Since you seem to be unsure of how these annotations affect how type checkers infer the relevant types, here is a full demonstration:

```py
from __future__ import annotations
from io import BytesIO
from typing import TypeVar

T = TypeVar("T", bound="BaseBlob")

class BaseBlob:
    def __init__(self, data: bytes):
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls: type[T], stream: BytesIO) -> T:
        return cls(stream.read(32))

class LimitedProofId(BaseBlob):
    pass

class TxId(BaseBlob):
    pass

class Delegation:
    def __init__(self, ltd_id: LimitedProofId):
        self.ltd_id = ltd_id

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, stream: BytesIO) -> Delegation:
        ltd_id = LimitedProofId.deserialize(stream)
        return cls(ltd_id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ltd = LimitedProofId(b"xyz")
    d = Delegation.deserialize(BytesIO(b"abc"))
    reveal_type(d.ltd_id)
    reveal_type(LimitedProofId.deserialize(BytesIO()))
    reveal_type(TxId.deserialize(BytesIO()))
```

The `mypy --strict` output is without errors:

```
note: Revealed type is "LimitedProofId"
note: Revealed type is "LimitedProofId"
note: Revealed type is "TxId"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

Comment: The `Delegation.__init__` method takes a `LimitedProofId` as a parameter, and **not** any other type of `BaseBlob`. AFAIK, ff I use the `TypeVar` solution, I also need to annotate the that `__init_` method to take a `T` type, and I specifically don't want `mypy` to allow any subclass of `BaseBlob` to be passed as argument.

Comment: @PiRK No, you don't. You annotate `Delegation.__init__` just like you did. It has nothing to do with the generic nature of `BaseBlob.deserialize`. You can easily test that this works as intended.

Comment: @PiRK I added a full working example to demonstrate that the annotations work exactly as you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Python 3.11 introduces the `Self` type hint for this. ([PEP 673](https://peps.python.org/pep-0673/) describes in more detail the code `Self` is intended to simplify, if you haven't upgraded to 3.11 yet.)

```
from typing import Self


class BaseBlob:
    def __init__(self, data: bytes):
        self.data = data

    @classmethod
    def deserialize(cls, stream: BytesIO) -> Self:
        return cls(stream.read(32))
```

Comment: I don't believe this works with a `classmethod`.

Comment: It's explicitly mentioned as a use case in both Pep 673 and the documentation for the `typing` module. Whether tools *support* this use yet is another matter. (`mypy` does not seem to; I haven't found any issues reported yet regarding whether it should or should not.)

Comment: Looks like support has been merged, but not yet released? https://github.com/python/mypy/pull/14041

Comment: I honestly hadn't used it myself until this question (I'm not actively using 3.11 in production). I did find it odd, as it was the first thing I tried.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks. I will have to wait a few years until I can set the minimum python version, to 3.11, sadly.

Comment: Be sure to check PEP 673, though; `typing.Self` is primarily intended to reduce the amount of boilerplate you need to write: defining a TypeVar name `Self`, using `type[Self]` when necessary, etc.